# How to access LAN IP Addresses : Cisco VPN Client

Tags: windows-10, vpn, remote-desktop, cisco-vpn-client

I've successfully configured Cisco VPN Client and connected.

And allow local LAN access

I don't know how to connect LAN IP Addresses.
I was trying to connect with Remote desktop connection, it's asking for username and pass but still it not connected.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  Believe it wants the actual username and password for the remote PC for example at my house it would be the computer name for the user and the password that you used to get past the logon  screen when you turn that computer on.

If you do not have a password on the remote PC sometimes you can leave that blank and still get in however the remote PC has to be set up to allow remote connections without authentication.